# Missing " ) " after argument list

Tags: javascript, arguments

I can't seem to find the solution to this problem:

```
 missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]   

}});
```

This is the file which is referred to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    for (i=0;i<40;i++) {
            var w = 14 * (parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + 1) - 1,
                h = 28 * (parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + 1) - 1;
        jQuery('').width(w).height(h).appendTo('article');
        }

            jQuery('#content').freetile();
             selector: 'article';
            });
```

I tried adding a accolade at the end, but it didn't work. Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your passing a malformed object, change to;

```
$('#content').freetile({ 
  selector: 'article' 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

What is `selector: 'article';` supposed to be doing? It *looks* like you might want to be specifying this as an option when initialising `freetile`:

```
jQuery("#content").freetile({selector: 'article'});
```

Comment: This is the reason I love this site. Thank you!

Comment: @1BJK903 You're very welcome. Quite fond of this place myself, too. (: